# How can I stop people from pressing return in my code

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, hashmap, bluej

Hi basically wrote this code, which stores a hashmap into an external text file So when the user types in write, the first value they type after write (index 1), and the second value at index(2), gets stored as a key and value respectively. The problem is that it all has to be on one line and if the user presses return after they type in "write" the system crashes. So how can I make it so that it doesn't allow the user to press return until they have typed a key and value?

This is my code,

```
if (input.contains("write")) {
    String key = input.get(1);
    String value = "";
    for(int i=2; i<input.size(); i++) {
        value = value + " " + input.get(i);
    }
    instruct.mapWrite(key, value);
}
```

I use a scanner class to get input then use the following method to split the string into an Array. This is how I can store the input into a HashMap.

```
public ArrayList<String> getInput() 
    {
        System.out.print("> ");                // print prompt
        String inputLine = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

        String[] wordArray = inputLine.split(" ");  // split at spaces

        // add words from array into ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String word : wordArray) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        return words;
    }
```

Comment: You can't prevent this behavior, and so instead you have to make your program immune to it. The details of a working solution will depend on the details of your code and problem.

Comment: You don't even tell how you produce that `input` of yours

Comment: you cant prevent. Perhaps, you want to prevent effects: 1 crash your app: test what is pressed (void, blank, ...) depends on input value 2 if you want the console not to show a CRLF, you have to work with the console ...

Comment: @fge  I have updated the code, so it show how the input is produced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent it at this level.

**But**

- Instead of dumb prompt, tell the user what you expect,
- check number of tokens (`if(wordArray.length < 3)`), print error message and ask again.